# Rails AJAX Not Working in Shopping Cart Order Items Create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have several instances of AJAX in a shopping cart setup in my app and none of them are working.  For example, it is supposed to use AJAX to update the menu bar icon saying how many items are in a cart when the a new item is initially added to the cart.

My form for a new `order_item` is like this:

```
<%= form_for order_item, remote: true do |f| %>
  <h4 class="text-right">Price: <span style="color: green"><%= number_to_currency product.price %></span></h4>
    <div class="input-group">
      <%= f.number_field :quantity, value: 1, class: "form-control", min: 1 %>
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <%= f.hidden_field :product_id, value: product.id %>
        <%= f.submit "Add to Cart", class: "btn btn-manly add_to_cart", style: "margin: 0" %>
        <span class="order_item_created hidden" style="color: red; font-weight: bolder">Added to Cart!</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

The javascript in `order_items/create.js.erb` looks like this:

```
<% if @order.errors.any? || @order_item.errors.any? %>
  alert("not valid.");
<% else %>
  $(".cart-text").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'layouts/cart_text') %>");
  $(".order_item_created").removeClass("hidden");
<% end %>
```

And my `OrderItemsController#Create` is this:

```
  def create
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.new(order_item_params)
    @order.save
    session[:order_id] = @order.id
  end
```

**Update** 
As requested, here are my `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
    resources :users, only: [:show, :update, :index]

  get 'home/index'
  root 'home#index'

  resources :products, only: [:index, :show]
  resource :cart, only: [:show]
  resources :order_items, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]
  resources :charges, only: [:new, :create]
  post 'charges/new'
  get 'charges/shipping'
  get 'charges/address'
  post 'charges/update_order'

  resources :orders, only: [:update, :edit, :show, :create, :index]
  get 'orders/update'
  put "orders/:id/mark_as_placed" => "orders#mark_as_placed", as: "mark_as_placed"
  put "orders/:id/mark_as_shipped" => "orders#mark_as_shipped", as: "mark_as_shipped"
  put "orders/:id/mark_as_cancelled" => "orders#mark_as_cancelled", as: "mark_as_cancelled"

end
```

I'm not an AJAX wizard, so I'm hoping the fix here is something relatively simple I'm overlooking.

**Additional Info**

Here are the server logs for what happens when an 'Add to Cart' button is clicked:

```
Started POST "/order_items" for ::1 at 2017-07-31 12:32:57 -0700
Processing by OrderItemsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "order_item"=>{"size"=>"Small", "quantity"=>"1", "product_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Add to Cart"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."active" = ? AND "products"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["active", "t"], ["id", 1]]
  SQL (1.4ms)  INSERT INTO "orders" ("subtotal", "created_at", "updated_at", "order_status_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["subtotal", 32.0], ["created_at", "2017-07-31 19:32:57.179361"], ["updated_at", "2017-07-31 19:32:57.179361"], ["order_status_id", 1]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "order_items" ("quantity", "product_id", "size", "order_id", "unit_price", "total_price", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["quantity", 1], ["product_id", 1], ["size", "Small"], ["order_id", 5], ["unit_price", 32.0], ["total_price", 32.0], ["created_at", "2017-07-31 19:32:57.184786"], ["updated_at", "2017-07-31 19:32:57.184786"]]
   (1.3ms)  commit transaction
  Order Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "order_items" WHERE "order_items"."order_id" = ?  [["order_id", 5]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "order_items" WHERE "order_items"."order_id" = ?  [["order_id", 5]]
  Rendered layouts/_cart_text.html.erb (11.4ms)
  Rendered order_items/create.js.erb (20.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 61ms (Views: 38.9ms | ActiveRecord: 4.2ms)
```

And here's `_cart_text.html.erb`:

```
<% if !current_order || current_order.order_items.count != 0 %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to cart_path do %>
      Cart <span style="background-color: red; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; border-radius: 7px; color: white"><%= current_order.order_items.count %></span>
    <% end %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you show your routes.rb?

Comment: would be good to see stack trace if any?Do you get any errors(look into terminal, browser console etc)?

Comment: @kasperite, no errors, console or otherwise.  :(

Comment: Can you update the question with the entire log that is generated upon form submit till the action completed?

Comment: @Pavan, the server logs are now at the end of the OP.  Thanks for looking!

Comment: `escape_javascript(render 'layouts/cart_text')` Shouldn't you call `render partial: "layouts/cart_text")`. If you do not need `partial` there seems to be missing : after render

Comment: @StephanePaquet, neither way works (with or without `partial:`), unfortunately.

Comment: Can you show us the `_cart_text.html.erb`? Also I can't see any tags with class `cart-text`. where do you have it?

Comment: @Pavan, the cart text partial was added to the OP.

Comment: Where do you have a tag with class name `cart-text`?

Comment: @Pavan AHHHHHHHH!  You're a genius!  That was it!  Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `$(".cart-text").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'layouts/cart_text') %>");` in `create.js.erb` but you don't have any **tag** matching with the selector of *class name* `cart-text`. This is the reason for your problem.

**Solution:**

Have a *tag(eg;- div, span or p etc)* with **class name** `cart-text`, so that the *JS* finds the **selector** and replace the html content of the tag with the partial code and prints the desired output. Something like this should work

```
<div class="cart-text"></div>
```